# Bipolar Disorder Patient data

Tags: neuroscience, matlab, ecg

Can someone provide me with an electrocardiogram signal of a bipolar patient? I'd like to have a trace obtained in an intermittent period, *i.e.*, when the patient is not experiencing a depressed or manic episode.

I have searched for it on [Pubmed physionet](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/14716615) but I could not find anything.